# Using Variation of Energy for a Dielectric to define the Electric Field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy, calculus, dielectric

I have been reading through Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics on my own, and I am confused about something in section 6.7.1, concerning the variation of total energy $U$ of a dielectric in the presence of a charged conductor.  This is given by (6.87)

$$\delta U = \int d^3 r \, \vec E \cdot \delta \vec D$$

where $\vec E$ is the total electric field, $\vec D$ is the auxiliary/displacement field.

Then, the books says (6.93)

$$ \vec E = 1/V(∂U/∂ \vec D)$$

Where $V$ is the volume of the dielectric.

I understand (ignoring any center of mass dependence) that using the logic of total differentials I can write

$$\delta U = (∂U/∂ \vec D) \cdot \delta \vec D$$

So it follows that

$$\int d^3 r \, \vec E \cdot \delta \vec D = (∂U/∂ \vec D) \cdot \delta \vec D$$

But the given equation for $\vec E$ only seems valid if $\vec E$ and $\vec D$ are constant over the volume, which isn't generally true. What am I misunderstanding? How does the equation for $\vec E$ given in the textbook follow?

Comment: Since there is total volume $V$ in formula 6.93, it looks like the author is limiting himself to the simple case where electric field is the same throughout the volume.

Comment: @JánLalinský but just before these equations, there is a diagram of a single, charged spherical conductor, embedded in the dielectric medium. The book says to think of this as the source of the electric field for this section of the text.  It would therefore have $1/r^2$ fall off, not be constant...